# splitting the URL using jQuery

Tags: ajax, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Can i get the help of you guys as i want i can do it with url**

I need to split the URL. and use last element as job_id, And then pass "jkdbsbd45JubJKAAASSYT" as job_Id.

```
URL: https://dev/job/?job_id=jkdbsbd45JubJKAAASSYT
```

Need to create this URL as below.

```
Need: https://dev/job/jkdbsbd45JubJKAAASSYT
```

**Thanx in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a WordPress related question but you could do this

```js
// creates a object from the array, one of the properies (search) contains the query
let url = new URL('https://dev/job/?job_id=jkdbsbd45JubJKAAASSYT');
// will create a object of all availalble query properites
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
// remove ? and everything after from url
url = url.href.substring(0, url.href.indexOf('?'));

// url + params.job_id is the final url, did a console.log so you could see it in the devtools console
console.log(url + params.job_id);
```

Comment: Still I am very happy that you helped me and gave your precious time.

Comment: One more question how to pass Id variable on this URL Like: let getId = "jkdbsbd45JubJKAAASSYT";  let url = new URL('https://dev/job/?job_id=', getId  );

Comment: @DKThakur In JS if you want to concatenate you need to use `+`, so going by what you want to achieve, you would need to do this `URL('https://dev/job/?job_id=' + getId)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this was out of my mind, and I am having an issue in WordPress, I do not have any knowledge of htaccess, can you help me?

Comment: @DKThakur You have a whole community that can help you. If you have a question about `.htaccess` that is WordPress related you can create a new question here, just make sure to check [how to ask a good question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just wanted to know that we can rewrite it with htaccess as we have split the job_id.

Comment: @DKThakur You can definitely use rewrite url for that but again, this seems like a question for SO, as it doesn't envole WordPress, so a better fit would be to ask this question there

Comment: I have added a new question from here, >>https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/400731/htaccess-rewrite-url-wordpress , you can check once, I will be happy if you have to edit something then you can.